# How to validate template driven form inside table with different fields?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In my ionic-angular application I am using Template driven forms, When I submit the form without touching the input fields it should display the error message, but in this case I am not able to display the error message in the span.

You can see the comments in which the error-message is written.
How do I validate this form?

**Page.html**

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" #form="ngForm">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <ion-input type="text" #c1 [(ngModel)]="c" name="c" required>
    </td>

    <td>
    <ion-input type="text" #c2 [(ngModel)]="d" name="d" required>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <span *ngIf="c1.pristine && c2.pristine && form.submitted">Plese enter codes</span> //error-message is not printing.

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" #form="ngForm" novalidate>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="c" name="c" id="c1" #c1="ngModel" required>
    <div [hidden]="!(c1.invalid && c1.touched)">Invalid.</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="d" name="d" id="c2" #c1="ngModel" required>
    <div [hidden]="!(c2.invalid && c2.touched)">Invalid.</div>
  </td>
</tr></table><button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.form.valid">Submit</button></form>
```